# phonegap android opacity artifacts

Tags: html, css, cordova, overlay, transparent

Im facing some bad looking artifacts when displaying transparent overlay with buttons. Anyone else faced/fixed that?

It happens on: Phonegap 2.9, Samsung Galaxy s3 with css:

```
#overlay.black {
background-color: #000000;
z-index: 99999;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60); }
```

[image: black artifacts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

at the end of css.

Answer (score 0):

newer versions seem to require `background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);` instead of `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`